# Strategy for Black&White game

Tags: probability, combinatorics, information-theory

Consider the following game. Let $n$ be a positive integer. There are two players, $\newcommand\A{\mathrm{A}}\A$ and $\newcommand\B{\mathrm{B}}\B$, and a referee.

- $\A$ and $\B$ first agree on a strategy. After this step, $\A$ and $\B$ cannot communicate.
- Initially, the referee chooses a sequence $\{c_i\}$ of length $n$, where each entry is either “black” or “white”. $\A$ is made aware of this entire sequence, but $\B$ is not.
- There are a series of $n$ rounds, where $\A$ and $\B$ simultaneously guess either “black” or “white”. During the $k^\text{th}$ round, the team wins a point if $\A$’s guess and $\B$’s guess are both equal to the $k^\text{th}$ entry of the referee’s sequence.
- After each round, $\B$ is told what $\A$’s guess was, and what the referee’s pick was, for that round. This means $\B$ makes each decision while aware of all information from previous rounds.

> Find a strategy for $\A$ and $\B$ so that they can guarantee winning $g(n)$ times, where $\lim\limits_{n\to+\infty}\frac{g(n)}n=\frac34$.

I have a strategy for which $\lim\limits_{n\to+\infty}\frac{g(n)}n=\frac35$. We will prove that $\A$ and $\B$ can win $3$ times in $5$ games. Here is the strategy. In the first game, $\A$ will guess the color that appears more in the subsequence $(c_2,c_3,c_4)$, and $\B$ will guess this color in game $2$ to $4$. If $c_2=c_3=c_4$, then $\A$ and $\B$ can win games $2$ to $4$ (so $3$ games have been won). Otherwise, $\A$ and $\B$ will lose exactly one game among $2$ to $4$. But $\A$ knows which game that will be, so they can guess $c_5$ in that game so that $\A$ and $\B$ win the fifth game.

I have no strategy for which $\lim\limits_{n\to+\infty}\frac{g(n)}n=\frac34$ though.

Comment: @DS $\newcommand\A{\rm A}\newcommand\B{\rm B}$For $\rm B~W~B~W~B$, in the first game, $\A$ shows white because there are more whites than blacks in "$\rm W~B~W$". Now $\B$ gets the sign and shows white on games $2$, $3$, and $4$. Also $\A$ shall show $\rm W$ in games $2$ and $4$ in order to win them. Moreover, $\A$ knows that game $3$ is bound to lose, so he will use it to tell $\B$ about the fifth game. Hence, he shows black in the third game, and so $\B$ gets this sign and will show black in the fifth game. In conclusion, games $2$, $4$, $5$ are won.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This problem is analyzed in the paper *Online Matching Pennies*, by Gossner, Hernandez, and Neyman, [available at this link](https://scholars.huji.ac.il/abrahamn/publications/online-matching-pennies). They prove that the upper limit for the proportion of rounds won is $x^*$, where $x^*\in (0,1)$ is the unique solution to
$$
x^*\cdot \log_2(\tfrac1{x^*})+(1-x^*)\cdot \log_2(\tfrac1{1-x^*})+(1-x^*)\cdot \log_23=1.
$$
That is, for any $x<x^*$, there exists a strategy for which $\lim_{n\to\infty} g(n)/n=x$. You can calculate $x^*\approx 0.8107$. This shows that a ratio of $3/4=0.75$ is attainable. However, the paper only gives a probabilistic proof of this fact. In what follows, I will give an explicit strategy which shows how to attain $\lim_n g(n)/n=3/4$.

---

Define a *covering code* $C$ of length $\ell$ and distance $d$ to be a subset $C\subseteq \{0,1\}^n$ such that, for any word $w\in \{0,1\}^n$, there exists $c\in C$ such that $w$ and $c$ differ in at most $d$ places.

For an example with $\ell=3$ and $d=1$, $C=\{000,111\}$ is an $(\ell,d)$-covering code. Given $w\in \{0,1\}^3$, if $w$ has two or more zeroes,  then $w$ is covered by $000$; otherwise, $w$ is covered by $111$.

We can use covering codes to construct strategies for the black and white game.

> **Claim:** Let $d,\ell,m$ be positive integers, where $d+m\le \ell$. Suppose there exists a covering code, $C$, with length $\ell$ and distance $d$, such that $$|C|\le \binom{\ell -d}{m}\cdot 2^d.$$ Then the players have a strategy for which $\lim_{n\to\infty} g(n)/n=m/\ell$.

*Proof:* We divide the entire process into blocks of length $\ell$. During each block, player $B$ will play a sequence which is equal to the codeword signaled by $A$ in the previous block. This codeword will agree with the referee's sequence in at least $\ell-d$ spots. Meanwhile, player A will choose a sequence which agrees with the referee's sequence and B's sequence at $m$ spots. There will be at least $\binom{\ell-d}{m}\cdot 2^d$ ways for $A$ to make this choice. $A$ uses this freedom to tell $B$ a codeword which agrees with the referee's next block of $\ell$ in at least $\ell-d$ places.

Here is how $A$ sends the message. Let $L$ be the set of  rounds in the current block, so $|L|=\ell$. The players first agree on a partitioning of  $L$ into two sets $D$ and $E$, so $L=E\cup D$ and $|D|=d$ and $|E|=\ell-d$. The only requirement is that all of the rounds where $B$ guessed incorrectly must be placed in $D$.

- First, $A$ will choose a subset $M\subseteq E$ such that $|M|=m$. For each round in $M$, $A$ will guess correctly, earning the team a point, while $A$ guesses incorrectly for the rounds in $E\setminus M$. There are $\binom{\ell-d}m$ ways that $A$ can choose $M$.
- Second, during all of the rounds in $D$, $A$ will simply use her guesses to send $B$ a binary sequence of length $d$, with $2^d$ options.

Since $A$ can make $\binom{\ell-d}{m}\times 2^d$ messages, and since $\binom{\ell-d}{m}\times 2^d\ge |C|$, $A$ has enough freedom to communicate a codeword in $C$ which differs in at most $d$ places from the referee's next block of $\ell$. Furthermore, during each round except the first, the team gets $m$ points out of $\ell$, proving an asymptotic ratio of $m/\ell$. $\tag*{$\square$}$

Let us consider an example of applying this **claim**. When $\ell=3, d=1$, we saw before that $C=\{000,111\}$ is a covering code. Letting $m=2$, we check the requirements of the claim: $$\binom{\ell-d}{m}\cdot 2^d=\binom{3-1}{2}\cdot 2^1=2=|C|,$$ so the requirement is satisfied. The **claim** gives a strategy with ratio $m/\ell=2/3$. This strategy is similar to the one you came up with; during each block of $3$, $A$ uses one bit to communicate the majority of the next block of $3$, while $B$ guesses the majority color each time (which was communicated during the previous round).

However, to attain a ratio of $3/4$, we need a much larger code. There is a summary of the best known covering codes at [Gerzson Kéri's website](http://old.sztaki.hu/%7Ekeri/codes/2_tables.pdf), which goes up to length $33$ and distance $10$. I searched through the whole table, and I found that the simplest code which could attain a ratio $3/4$ was the code with length $24$ and distance $3$, consisting of $2^{13}=8192$ codewords. Calling this code $C$, we can obtain $C$ by modifying the binary Golay code, $G_{23}$ ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_Golay_code)). Specifically,
$$
C=\{v\oplus b \mid v\in G_{23}, b\in \{0,1\}\}
$$
Here, $\oplus$ is the concatenation operation. That is, you extend $G_{23}$ by appending a $0$ to all vectors, and appending a $1$ to all vectors, thereby doubling the number of codewords, while preserving the covering distance of $3$. Letting $m=18$, we check the conditions of the claim are satisfied:
$$
\binom{24-3}{18}\cdot 2^3=10640>2^{13}=|C|,
$$
We can then apply the **claim** to get a strategy with a ratio of $18/24=3/4$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the source. It seems that I still need loads of knowledge to understand it.